# How can I ensure a custom CMake command is running before any dependencies are built?

Tags: cmake

So, I have a target `units` which has as dependencies all the static library targets in my CMake project.

Part of the reason I bother with `units` is so that I can run some stats on the libraries.

I would like to write the stats to single text log, but before I do so, I need to make sure the log is empty, so I set up a custom command to do this, with a target of `units`, with the `PRE_BUILD` option:

```
add_custom_target(units)
add_custom_command(
    TARGET  units
    PRE_BUILD
    COMMENT "Clearing log"
    COMMAND echo "" > ${UTIL_LOG_PATH}
)
```

Unfortunately, this command actually runs *after* the build of the dependencies of `units`. How do I ensure that this happens *before* the dependencies are built?

Comment: "_I would like to write the stats to single text log, but before I do so, I need to make sure the log is empty,_" in which stage of your build process do you write those stats? why not add the commands that collect the stats as part of the same custom command that clears the previous log? (side-question: why clear the previous log in the first place? Won't it just get overwritten when you write the new one?) You can have multiple commands per custom command. And then you can just make that custom command depend on all the targets that it collects stats for.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly the PRE_BUILD only works for Visual Studio Generators as you can read [here in the official documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html#build-events). On other platforms and generators it will execute after the target is built.

There are two approaches based on your example. You could firstly have a few commands on your custom target so you don't need to have an additional PRE_BUILD command:

```
add_custom_target(units 
    COMMAND echo "" > ${UTIL_LOG_PATH}
    COMMAND ...
)
```

If you want to ensure that your command for clearing log is executed before any target though you just simple need a custom target and the command `add_dependencies()` which you can read more about [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_dependencies.html).

```
add_custom_target(clearing_log
    COMMENT "Clearing log"
    COMMAND echo "" > ${UTIL_LOG_PATH}
)
```

... and then the following:

```
add_custom_target(units)
add_dependencies(units clearing_log)
```

Comment: `add_custom_target(a DEPENDS b)` is not equivalent to `add__custom_target(a) add_dependencies(a b)`. The former is used for files and the latter for targets...

Comment: Indeed I've edited my answer

Comment: `PRE_BUILD` works fine on other generators. From the _very same_ documentation you linked: "On other generators, run just before `PRE_LINK` commands."

Comment: Yeah but what is the PRE_LINK for custom targets?